# Using sheet1's two columns how to match with Sheet2 column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

```
VLOOKUP(AS:AS,[Li.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$Y$7752,4,FALSE)
```

- Sheet1: ID,EMAIL ID
- Sheet2: EMAIL ID

Comment: Can you add some data to these two sheets?  What are you trying to match here?

Comment: Your first parameter should be a single cell, not a range...  try just `AS` instead of `AS:AS`

Comment: @Hambone Your suggestion `AS` is no valid reference at all. But `AS:AS` is actually a single cell, because it represents the cell of the current row in column AS. So if you are in cell B2 writing `=AS:AS` is the same as `=AS2`. So this is the correct way to use it.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ -- oh my gosh...  it's going to be one of those days.  Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to depict what I am hoping is the issue. See the pictures below. you are matching `Email ID` from Sheet 1-> `Email ID` in Sheet 2.
You need the first variable in the `Vlookup function` to be the cell with Sheet2 Email ID, Say A2, (this is very important: make sure the in the table range (Email ID is the first row, [Column B])

[image]

Then this should work:

```
VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$B$2:$C$5,2,FALSE)
```

Add new column on the right of Sheet 1. see below:
[image]

Comment: sheet1: ID , Email id  match with sheet2: Email id and final output I want matched ID+Email ID

Can you help on this?

Comment: @PrabhakarBalgeri, see modified.

Comment: I need result matched ID and Email Id

Comment: when you say matched ID and email Id, do you mean, if say "test@me.you" is matched, you want to return "test@me.you"+1?

Comment: Yes I want result - 'test@me.you'+1 from sheet 1

Comment: okay, you  will need a double vlookups, one for the email and one for the id. Something like: =VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet1!$B$2:$C$5,1,FALSE)&VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet1!$B$2:$C$5,2,FALSE)

Comment: This one add a 'plus' between the two vlookups:  =VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet1!$B$2:$C$5,1,FALSE)&"+"&VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet1!$B$2:$C$5,2,FALSE)

Comment: Can you elaborate the attributes of VLOOKUP functions i.e which attribute is taken from which sheet. and please provide example with screenshots

Comment: By using this =VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet1!$B$2:$C$5,1,FALSE)&"+"&VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet1!$B$2:$C$5,2,FALSE) , I got '#N/A' then what I do next?

Comment: @PrabhakarBalgeri, try with the first vlookup first. the second one is only changing the index. If you get '#N/A' it means that 'A3' is not found in the range Sheet1!$B$2:$C$5. Make sure that the range Sheet1!$B$2:$C$5, has the first column as 'Email ID', so B2 column.

Comment: Actually, I think the fastest way, send a sample file with the two tabs (sheet1, sheet2) through SO and tell what you are wanting to do

Comment: Can show step by step with screenshot, because i'm not getting it?

Comment: use the screenshots I sent already above. it is okay and works. place all data like in the screenshot sheet1 and sheet2. then use that vlookup fuction.

Comment: how to attach sheet?

Comment: got it. do you know you can put them all in one file?

Comment: in the same file, this formula gives you the email from sheet2 matching the email in sheet1. =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$B$1:$C$4,1,FALSE). Notice the table starts from B. Instead of A.

Comment: You need the email column to be the first in the range. So from colum B->

Comment: Then add a new column 'NewID' at C after B. so when you change the index, it will pick up the Id.

Comment: Left me know if you are there?

Answer (score 0):

see it in action here: using `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$B$1:$C$4,2,FALSE) for IDS` and

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$B$1:$C$4,1,FALSE) for email
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try with the two sheets together in one file. So sheet 1 and sheet 2 combined. Let me know if it is okay.